# How do I complete the "Rescue Frank" mission in Dead Island?

Tags: dead-island

I am on the mission where you are in the lab and someone named Frank is surrounded by zombies and you have to save him.

I started it but I died so I went to do another mission. Now when I try to complete this one the doors to get to him are closed and there is no way to open it.

I have completed every other mission and tried everything but it still doesnt work.

What do I do?

Comment: Do note that there is actually a game called glitch, and therefore that tag should not be used if your question is about glitches in a game.

Answer (score 1):

The only other choice you have is to attempt to join another session in multiplayer where the door is not closed.  Try hanging around in the area, if someone else its in that section you'll see a notification that allows you to join them.